# Multiple select in PostgreSQL CTE

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to convert temporary tables to CTE http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html in PostgreSQL. In the stored procedure I have created a temporary table and have inserted into the temporary table two times using two different select queries. But when converting to CTE how can I achieve this? It does not support to select multiple times

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE breakup_amount
  (
  estimate_id integer,
  breakup_total numeric
  )
  ON COMMIT DROP;

Insert Into breakup_amount
Select SP.estimate_id,
       sum(SP.from_bank+SP.from_customer) as breakup_total
                    FROM sales_payment_breakups SP 
where 
SP.breakup_date <= due_date and SP.milestone_id is null
group by SP.estimate_id;


Insert Into breakup_amount
Select SP.estimate_id,
       sum(SP.from_bank+SP.from_customer) as breakup_total
                    FROM sales_payment_breakups SP 
where 
SP.breakup_date >= due_date and SP.project_id is null
group by SP.estimate_id;
```

I can write the first insertion as

```
with breakup_amount as (
Select SP.estimate_id,
           sum(SP.from_bank+SP.from_customer) as breakup_total
                        FROM sales_payment_breakups SP 
    where 
    SP.breakup_date <= due_date and SP.milestone_id is null
    group by SP.estimate_id
)
```

But then how can I do the second insertion?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Inserting into the temporary table is fine, but then what do you do with that data before the table is dropped?

Comment: @Patrick       I am creating a report using JasperReports. It does not support temporary tables. So I want to convert temporary tables to CTE. How can I achieve the above query using WITH clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to do two `SELECT`s to assemble similar data (i.e. same columns/data types) into one result set, you can use a `UNION` instead of a CTE:

```
SELECT SP.estimate_id, sum(SP.from_bank+SP.from_customer) AS breakup_total
  FROM sales_payment_breakups SP 
  WHERE SP.breakup_date <= due_date AND SP.milestone_id IS NULL
  GROUP BY SP.estimate_id
UNION
SELECT SP.estimate_id, sum(SP.from_bank+SP.from_customer) AS breakup_total
  FROM sales_payment_breakups SP 
  WHERE SP.breakup_date >= due_date AND SP.project_id IS NULL
  GROUP BY SP.estimate_id;
```